# Parsing twitter entities from JSON to R

Tags: json, r, twitter

I have obtained a collection of tweets in JSON format and I want to convert them to a R data.frame. 
I use the following code for conversion (using rjson library):

```
lines <- readLines(file,encoding = "UTF-8")
json <- lapply(1:length(lines),function(i) as.data.frame(t(unlist(fromJSON(lines[i])))))
json <- lapply(1:length(json),function(i) json[[i]])
data <- rbind.fill(json)
```

Data conversion is well performed, except for *userMentionEntities*. I have found that only the first user mention can be retrieved. Instead of a *userMentionEntities* column, the converted data.frame includes a column for every userMention field (id, name, screenName, start, end,_class), whose values are those of the first mentioned user.

Is there a way to include all user mentions in a tweet in the data.frame?
Should I convert tweets data to R in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

The streamr package has a useful [parser](https://github.com/pablobarbera/streamR/blob/master/streamR/R/parseTweets.R). Twitter objects can get confusing (nested data frame within nested data frame), but I think I mostly sorted it out with [my parser](https://github.com/mkearney/tfse/blob/master/R/data.frame.objects.R).

Comment: I have tried your solution and I get this error. I am new to R and don't know how to fix it. `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "try_catch"
Calls: map_df ... as_data_frame -> lst -> lst_ -> <Anonymous> -> eval -> eval
Execution halted`

Comment: My mistake. That's a smaller version of the function tryCatch() that you would have to send to your workspace prior to using it. If you want to write your own finction(s), check out https://github.com/mkearney/tfse/blob/master/R/data.frame.objects.R and https://github.com/pablobarbera/streamR/blob/master/streamR/R/parseTweets.R. Or you could just install one of those packages and use the code that's already written.

Comment: When trying to install tfse packet, I get the following error: `Note: the specification for S3 class “AsIs” in package ‘jsonlite’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘DBI’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
Warning: S3 method ‘c.string’ was declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: get_package_pdf, get_wave, get_wave_data, gg_cols, load_tokens, sn2id, wave_path_name
Error: loading failed `

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It should be fixed now, but I'm sure more problems will reveal themselves soon enough!

Comment: Thanks to you for your help! I keep on with my error feedback :$: `Error: Variables must be length 1 or 1.
Problem variables: urls, user_mentions, hashtags, place_long1, place_long2, place_long3, place_long4, place_lat1, place_lat2, place_lat3, place_lat4, media_id, media_url, media_type.`

Comment: Thank you for trying it. I've still got a lot of error decoding and configuring of package dependencies to do. I'm still relatively new to package development, so having other people tell me what's working/not working is a major help.